# Accessing info inside links in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Background: I have a Google Sheet that has some links in it. Of course, links don't always have the contents of what you are looking for the URL, so trying to search for it later is hard.

Question: Is it possible to peek into the contents of the website to find a keyword?

Ex: Let's say I have google.com, cs.stackexchange.com, stackexchange.com/bunnyrabbits (made this one up) and the last link contains words like "snake" and "turtle". If I CTRL+F "snake", there will be no results. Is there a way to look into the link without having to check each link one by one?

(Note that the tag on the bottom is because I don't have enough reputation to put general, sorry)

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hello, there aren't any results I could find on the problem, sorry.